# MySQL Inner Join 2 Tables and Count Table 2 by ID from Table 1

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have two table, and want to join both of them. Then i want to get the count total result from Table B if one or more data from Table A is have the same ID on Table B. Here is the example.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've already try like this, but it only give me two result, not like what i want:

```
SELECT 
table_a.*,
table_b.*,
count(*) as total
FROM 
    table_a,
    table_b
WHERE
    table_b.id_tblA = table_a.id_tblA
GROUP BY
    table_b.id_tblB
```

Comment: You need `GROUP BY`

Comment: @PM77-1 I already try GROUP BY, but still not work for me

Comment: An inner join isn't going to return the specified result. We can use an outer join, with a group by and an aggregate (count or sum). As another option, we can use a correlated subquery in the select list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT
    table_a.id_tblA, table_a.tblA_name, 
    (SELECT count(*) FROM table_b WHERE table_b.id_tblA = table_a.id_tblA)
FROM
    table_a;
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use a left join and case when

```
  SELECT 
  table_a.id_tblA,
  table_a.Name,
  sum(case when table_b.id_tblB is null then 0 else 1 end) total
  FROM  table_a
  left  join table_b on table_b.id_tblA = table_a.id_tblA
  group by table_a.id_tblA, table_a.Name
```

Comment: missing `table_b on ` after `left  join`

Comment: Try to add the missing 'table_b on' but still not work for me

Comment: @JhonnyJr. : also change third expression in select list....  `SUM(CASE WHEN table_b.id_tblB IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS total`